# List with <set> tag in beans xml-configuration behaves as Set

Tags: java, spring

I'm reading "Spring Recipes" book and try to investigate Spring "magic" with examples. That's what I have.
Bean class **SequenceGenerator**:

```
public class SequenceGenerator {
    private List<Object> suffixes;
    //..... 
    public void setSuffixes(List<Object> suffixes) {
        this.suffixes = suffixes;
    }
    public synchronized String getSequence() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();            
        for (Object suffix : suffixes) {
            buffer.append(suffix);
            buffer.append("-");
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        SequenceGenerator generator =
                (SequenceGenerator) context.getBean("sequenceGeneratorSet");
        System.out.println(generator.getSequence());
    }
}
```

Xml config:

```
<bean id="sequenceGeneratorSet" class="com.apress.springrecipes.sequence.SequenceGenerator">
        <property name="initial" value="100000"/>
        <property name="suffixes">
            <set>
                <value>A</value>
                <value>A</value>
                <bean class="java.net.URL">
                    <constructor-arg value="http" />
                    <constructor-arg value="www.apress.com" />
                    <constructor-arg value="/" />
                </bean>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In xml I have intentionally used  tag to watch the result. Also I have written the same value, "A", twice. I noticed that Spring injected ArrayList for "suffixes" property, as its type definition in bean class. But it behaves like set on output, containing only one "A" value. Does anybody have an idea how Spring can internally figure it out?

Comment: Probably first creates a `Set<Object>` with the objects you set and then sets the `suffixes` variable with a list whose values are based on this set, in code `suffixes = new ArrayList<Object>(theSet);`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's a little longer than that, but you've got the right idea.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes, I guess that there must be more logic behind this since it is parsing a XML file and creating the data probably using reflection, but I don't really like to go into details in this case, just understand the main idea :).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I've answered a few of these in depth question recently by going through debuggers and source code and it's really enlightening. It took like 25 minutes, but I think it's worth it :P.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis by the way, I think that Spring code should be redesigned to stop using too many `if-else` and use a `Map` or an `enum` to enhance the current design.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I don't think I'm anywhere near the knowledge level I'd want to be to comment on that. I will say it would be a huge endeavor. Maybe you can contribute to the Spring team. (I will say there are tons of `null` checks which I hate.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the magic happens inside org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomCollectionEditor.
It's responsible for creating a property of a certain type (List in your case) from context-supplied object (Set in your example):

```
public void setValue(Object value) {
    if (value == null && this.nullAsEmptyCollection) {
        super.setValue(createCollection(this.collectionType, 0));
    }
    else if (value == null || (this.collectionType.isInstance(value) && !alwaysCreateNewCollection())) {
        // Use the source value as-is, as it matches the target type.
        super.setValue(value);
    }
    else if (value instanceof Collection) {
        // Convert Collection elements.
        Collection source = (Collection) value;
        Collection target = createCollection(this.collectionType, source.size());
        for (Object elem : source) {
            target.add(convertElement(elem));
        }
        super.setValue(target);
    }
    else if (value.getClass().isArray()) {
        // Convert array elements to Collection elements.
        int length = Array.getLength(value);
        Collection target = createCollection(this.collectionType, length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            target.add(convertElement(Array.get(value, i)));
        }
        super.setValue(target);
    }
    else {
        // A plain value: convert it to a Collection with a single element.
        Collection target = createCollection(this.collectionType, 1);
        target.add(convertElement(value));
        super.setValue(target);
    }
}


protected Collection createCollection(Class collectionType, int initialCapacity) {
    if (!collectionType.isInterface()) {
        try {
            return (Collection) collectionType.newInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Could not instantiate collection class [" + collectionType.getName() + "]: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else if (List.class.equals(collectionType)) {
        return new ArrayList(initialCapacity);
    }
    else if (SortedSet.class.equals(collectionType)) {
        return new TreeSet();
    }
    else {
        return new LinkedHashSet(initialCapacity);
    }
}
```

So, as the first step a Set is created from your context definition and after that it's transformed to the List by PropertyEditor implementation. Check out other PropertyEditors from the same package, some of them perform similar implicit conversions, e.g. Map <-> Properties and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Spring has an immense stack of method calls to generate your context. When it parses your XML context, Spring generates a `RootBeanDefinition` object that describes your bean (class, properties, etc.) and `PropertyValues` objects that contain names of the properties (`<property>`) and their values.

In this case, it will create a `ManagedSet` which is a

> Tag collection class used to hold managed Set values, which may
>   include runtime bean references (to be resolved into bean objects)

to hold your `A` and `URL` values.

The above is done before any of the actual bean objects' fields are initialized (`BeanPostProcessors` do their thing, proxying, etc.), although the instance itself (defaulting field values to `null`) is created. You can see this by creating an empty constructor and adding a breakpoint while debugging.

Further down the line, in `AbstractApplicationContext#refresh()`, `finishBeanFactoryInitialization()` gets called where the initialization finally happens. For each `BeanDefinition` created earlier and the corresponding `PropertyValues`, Spring calls `applyPropertyValues()` on the `BeanFactory` creating your beans.

For your `suffixes` field, Spring figures out that the type expected and the actual type don't match. A `TypeConverterDelegate` will figure out which `PropertyEditor` or `ConversionService` to use to convert from the `PropertyValues` (the `ManagedSet`) to the actual `Field` type, ie. `List`. In this case it uses a `CustomCollectionEditor`. That editor calls `createCollection()` with the type of collection your `Field` is declared as. For you, that's `List`. So

```
protected Collection createCollection(Class collectionType, int initialCapacity) {
    if (!collectionType.isInterface()) {
        try {
            return (Collection) collectionType.newInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Could not instantiate collection class [" + collectionType.getName() + "]: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else if (List.class.equals(collectionType)) { // US HERE
        return new ArrayList(initialCapacity);
    }
    else if (SortedSet.class.equals(collectionType)) {
        return new TreeSet();
    }
    else {
        return new LinkedHashSet(initialCapacity);
    }
}
```

It creates an `ArrayList`. For each element in our earlier `Set`, it will try to convert the element if necessary and then add it to the `ArrayList`. Using a `BeanWrapperImpl`, it then sets the property value. To do this it finds your setter `Method` through reflection and invokes it with the `ArrayList`.

Spring performs this same logic for each bean and each property declared in the context.